# Accessing data stored in redis using python

Tags: python, redis, yii2

I am saving data in redis using PHP Yii2 framework. YII2 uses hash to store data.The same data i am trying to retrieve in python. I know the key of which i need data. How can i get the value of that key in python?

This is what i get in python

hashed key stored using YII2 : `220a9a963c13278a1f7dceeb28851a30`

value against the above key : 
`a:2:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:11:"filter_name";s:10:"Permission";}}i:1;N;}`

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis(host=host,port=port,password=password, db=12,decode_responses=False)
key_list = r.keys('*')
for keys in key_list:
    print("{} >>> {}".format(keys, r.get(keys)))
```

Expected output : value of key

Actual output : `None`

Answer (score 0):

try this out and let me know if it works,
Explanation: since you mentioned that data is stored using hash (**hset**) then you must use **hget** to retrieve the values against that datatype.

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis(host=host,port=port,password=password, db=12,decode_responses=False)
key_list = r.keys('*')
for keys in key_list:
    print("{} >>> {}".format(keys, r.hgetall(keys)))
```

Comment: I checked the type of key using r.type(keys). It gives me string type. so the key is not of hash type which gives this error : WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value.

Comment: can you print out the keys? like this `for keys in key_list:
print(keys)`

Comment: i have mentioned one of the key and value in the description itself.